# Google Play Services crashing constantly

Tags: crashes, google-play-services, location-services

My wife has a Samsung Galaxy Note 4, she didn't install any new apps on the phone today or yesterday, but now her Google Play services is crashing constantly (like every 5-10 seconds).

We tried the obvious stuff:

- Uninstall a bunch of apps she's not using
- Close all the apps
- Reboot lots of times

[image]

So my next step was to enable USB Debugging and Connect with ADB.  This gave me this clue when the error dialog shows up:

```
07-17 19:14:05.078 18130-18130/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 18130
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationService: java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 3620 uid 10015
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3817)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:221)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1882)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 3620 uid 10015
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
       at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:217)
       at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:484)
       at android.app.AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.java:466)
       at irq.a(:com.google.android.gms:162)
       at irq.a(:com.google.android.gms:210)
       at irq.a(:com.google.android.gms:199)
       at idq.e(:com.google.android.gms:457)
       at idq.<init>(:com.google.android.gms:164)
       at com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms:107)
       at com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationChimeraService.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:85)
       at com.google.android.chimera.container.ServiceProxy.onCreate(:com.google.android.gms:151)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3807)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1882) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I keyed in on this portion of the error:

```
Unable to create service com.google.android.location.internal.server.GoogleLocationService
```

So I revoked Location permissions from a few more applications, and changed the Location Mode from "High Accuracy" to GPS Only.  At that point the error message became manageable when not in an application that needs it, but still comes up very frequently if I open Google Maps.

What else should I be trying to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have root access to that device, so you could find out which app has UID 10015? According to the logcat, that's the one having too many alarms registered and thus causing the main issue. If you don't have root, you could try `adb shell dumpsys package >packagedump.txt` and then scan `packagedump.txt` for "userId=10015".

Comment: @Izzy - thx, I will try that tonight and report back with what process is doing it, and even if it's always the same process.  I'm leaning towards this being a larger GPS problem, so it could be showing the error for every attempt to get GPS regardless of the app

Comment: Thanks @Izzy - I don't have root, that command worked, but did not contain any PIDs, and when I connected it to ADM, I couldn't see the PIDs (non rooted device).  UID 10015 shows up as "shared user" and all the google play services show as owned by it.

Comment: OK, that makes identification tricky. Most likely some GService acts as "agent" here (the app requests the alarm, but the service turns up being the one trying to create it – similar situation as with location wakelocks). If you skim the logs immediately before that stack trace: are there any clues that some app does try to schedule alarms? (I saw you already identified the culprit – so if you saved that log, you could simply "grep" for the package name to see in which context it turns up – would help to know for similar cases in the future)

Comment: Just cleared the cache and problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort before resetting her phone, I saw she still had "Pokémon Go" on her phone.  I uninstalled that and the problem went away.  It must have some background services too, because the app wasn't running in the task swap view.

When I reinstalled the app, I picked her profile, and it reloaded.  The phone worked fine for the last few hours, so it seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common problem when [installing google services on Genymotion emulator](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en), Seems to me like version related problem, Try to go to google play store and update the app. (You can get new vesrion apk [here](http://www.droidviews.com/download-google-apps-gapps-for-your-android-device-on-gbicsjb/))

Comment: The "here" link is interesting.  Is there an official place to get those directly from google instead of 3rd party?  The phone is stock from Verizon (not rooted).

Comment: Can you update your app directly from google play store?

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys everyone who is facing repeated issues of Google Play Service crashes.
I'll give you a simple method to resolve this issue.

Steps to Follow:

1. Go to Settings menu.
2. Click on option APPS and select "Google Play Services".
3. Under the info. Click on "Uninstall Updates".
4. Make sure your security software is **OFF**.
5. Try running YouTube and it will ask you to Update "Google Play Service".
6. Update it and run YouTube again.
7. Check back, your problem should be Solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found similer issue. 
What I found most of the time I found it is because of weather app. 
Disable locations permissions of weather app. 
And check.

Answer (score -1):

Google Play Services stopped may be due to various reasons.I would recommend you to try out these steps-
1. Check for enough memory on your Phone.
2.Try to Check the Play Store. Is it working fine? If not then try to force stop and clear the Data.
3.Try to update your Play store Services.
4.If you want to get rid of this error that pops up on your Screen.Just Go to Settings>Apps>All>Search for Play Store Services and Press the Disable Button to stop this error screen forever.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure it's the store.  I think it's GPS related.

Comment: "Search for Play Store Services and Press the Disable Button to stop this error screen forever" – yo. And stop all functionality based on those services right along, which is quite a lot? No more GCM notifications, no playstore, no network location etc.pp. I don't think that's a price Baronz would be willing to pay. Apart from which I doubt very much that any of those steps helps: from the logs, to me it rather looks like a rogue application is scheduling far too much alerts.

Comment: @Baronz,Follow the steps that I mentioned and let me know if it helps.